# Is there a way to Future.get() in the same method without blocking the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, future, executorservice

We have timseries observations being processed for thousands of metrics and they all come down to the same method to be processed via their respective processors. I'm sending the observations to their respective processor in a multithreaded way but the future.get() is blocking the main thread longer than expected. Is there a way to improve it?

```
  ExecutorService[] pools = new ExecutorService[Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()];
...
  @Override
  public Observation apply(final Observation observation) {
    Callable<Observation> task = new Processor(observation);
    int hash = Math.abs(observation.getMetricId().hashCode());

    Future<Observation> result = pools[hash % pools.length].submit(task);
    try {
      return result.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Why are you having multiple pools and doing distribution yourself? Pools are good at distributing themselves, better than you are. This kinda defeats the purpose of pools. You cant return a result of the future without waiting for it. That is just flawed. You have to change your design. Let your method return a `Future<Observation>` and then the user can decide how to handle it, when to block or whether he wants to schedule a task upon completion and so on. I suggest you take a look at modern multithreading in Java revolving around `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Is the goal of the `Processor#call` method to return a modified `Observation`? I’m trying to clarify why you have `Observation` os both input and output..

Comment: @BasilBourque yes Processor modifies the Observation. And the modified observation is being returned by processor then by Future.get()

Comment: @BasilBourque it is Observation, mistyped while editing.

Comment: If the current thread has no other work to do, if you are immediately asking for the result, why are you processing the Observation object on a background thread?

Comment: why must you run on main thread? and why must you run in blocking mode?

Comment: @Zabuzard for a metric all its observations should be processed in order, so if thread A is processing observation a, observation b should be processed by A only once observation a has been processed. That's why distributing myself on hashcode

Comment: @dungtavan because I need to maintain the order of incoming observations

Comment: You can use a single pool for that and setup a queue of tasks like `pool.submit(firstTask).andThen(secondTask).andThen(thirdTask).andThen(fourthTask)...`, just take a look at `CompletableFuture`, as said. Actually, you might also be fine with the default pool already, so you can just write `CompletableFuture.submit(firstTask).andThen(secondTask)...`. For real, there are so much better solutions to what you are attempting here.

Comment: You just want to free your main thread, right? (I mean is it ok to run on other thread?)